# Joomla not display view for task

Tags: php, url, joomla

I have component called mycomponent

**models**
paypal.php

**controllers**
paypal.php

**views**

**paypal**
view.html.php
index.html

tmpl(folder)
default.php
index.html

In controller i have this code

```
 <?php


// No direct access.
defined('_JEXEC') or die;


jimport('joomla.application.component.controlleradmin');

/**
 * Objectdefects list controller class.
 */
class MycomponentControllerPaypal extends JControllerAdmin
{
         public function paypaldetails()
    {
        $model = $this->getModel('paypal');
        // Get token
                $token = urlencode(htmlspecialchars(JRequest::getVar('token')));
        if (!$token)
        {
            // Missing $token parameter
            $app = JFactory::getApplication();
            $app->enqueueMessage(JText::_('COM_INSTALLER_MSG_MISSING_TOKEN'));
        }
        else
        {
            // Install plugin
            $model->paypaldetails($token);
        }
    }
}
```

In model i have this fragment of code

```
 public function paypaldetails($token){
            $environment=  $this->environment;
            // Add request-specific fields to the request string.
           $nvpStr = "&TOKEN=$token";
// Execute the API operation; see the PPHttpPost function above.
$httpParsedResponseAr = $this->PPHttpPost('GetExpressCheckoutDetails', $nvpStr);
//var_dump($httpParsedResponseAr);
if("SUCCESS" == strtoupper($httpParsedResponseAr["ACK"]) || "SUCCESSWITHWARNING" == strtoupper($httpParsedResponseAr["ACK"])) {

    $paypaldetails=array();
        $paypaldetails["firstname"]= $httpParsedResponseAr['FIRSTNAME'];
        $paypaldetails["lastname"]  = $httpParsedResponseAr["LASTNAME"];
        $paypaldetails["countrycode"] = $httpParsedResponseAr["COUNTRYCODE"];
       $this->paypaldetails=$paypaldetails;
       $a=$this->paypaldetails;
       var_dump($a);
} else  {
    exit('GetExpressCheckoutDetails failed: ' . print_r($httpParsedResponseAr, true));
}
        }
```

In view/template/default.php i have this

```
<?php
// no direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
// Import CSS
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addStyleSheet('components/com_mycomponent/assets/css/defects.css');
        $results = $this->items;
        var_dump($results);
        echo 'Firstname: '.$results[firstname];
        echo '<br>Lastname: '.$results[lastname];
        echo '<br>Countrycode: '.$results[countrycode];
```

When i run this url `index.php?option=com_fewostar&view=paypal&task=paypal.paypaldetails&token=EC-92L7275685367793U&PayerID=TGWAUKNJLH2WL`
I view first  var_dump($a); located on model, but second var_dump($results); located in views/paypal/tmpl/default.php not display, and field in view not display. for any reason this url not call view.  When i run this url `index.php?option=com_fewostar&view=paypal` code without task, view is display. but for this url
`index.php?option=com_fewostar&view=paypal&task=paypal.paypaldetails&token=EC-92L7275685367793U&PayerID=TGWAUKNJLH2WL` no display view. How i call view for this task, may be i need other view file, different of default.php?

Answer (score 3):

I see a couple of problems here.
First, the code is not exactly using Joomla MVC style (even if it works for you, might be harder for people familiar with Joomla to debug).

**Model method should be called `getPaypaldetails` and return something**

```
public function getPaypaldetails()
{
    // For Joomla 1.7+ use JInput instead of JRequest (deprecated)
    $token = JFactory::getApplication()->input->getVar('token');

    // some code

    return $paypaldetails;
}
```

**view.html.php should and get and data from model and assign to itself**

```
public function display($tpl = null)
{
    // Get some data from the models
    $items = $this->model->get('paypaldetails');

    // If data are incorrect, show nice error message
    // ...

    $this->items = $items;
}
```

**View Layout file should be placed in `/com_fewostar/views/paypal/tmpl/default.php`**

Answer (score 1):

By default, the view is only called by the "display" task (which is the default task). Since you use your own task, you need to either redirect to the view after your task is finished or try to load the display function at the end.